# Does anyone know the meaning of this character ()?

Tags: characters

The only things I found about it is its vietnamese reading "khuôn" and that it is used in  (meaning "face").

[image]

Comment: Based on the hex code (U+237C2), I have added an image of the character, as some browser default to fonts that do not include this glyph.

Comment: I don't find any explanation of the character. But you can also tell us where did you see "". We may try to understand it with contexts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Nom Foundation has a [lookup tool](http://www.nomfoundation.org/nom-tools/Nom-Dictionary) that might give a clue:

[image]

Although I don't understand which entry belongs to which character, or what the relationship among the characters is (Han Nom was less standardized than Chinese Hanzi, so some of the 4 shown here might even be distinct variants), my best guess based on the expressions is `'mold/mould'` as in [molding/moulding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molding_%28process%29) (or the derived meanings like 'shape/pattern'). The 木 radical might also support the meaning, since molds tended be made from wood in earlier times (additionally, the Mandarin Chinese equivalent for mold/mould is also based on the 木 radical: 模 [mó/mú]).

EDIT: If the two-character expression used in your description is transliterated as 'khuôn mặt' (literally "face shape"), I guess the character in the title means 'shape'.

Answer (score 2):

This is Vietnamese-only CJKV Characters, it is created by Vietnam. Meaning is :
[shape, pattern, mold](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/khu%C3%B4n).